# Difference between Apache commons-collections' synchronizedList() and java.util.Collections.synchronizedList()

Tags: java, list, collections, synchronization, apache-commons-collection

Any difference between [java.util.Collections.synchronizedList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) and [Apache commons-collections' ListUtils.synchronizedList()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-).

Any reason to prefer one over the other?

Comment: In the Apache Javadoc: "This method is just a wrapper for Collections.synchronizedList(List)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [java doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) clearly states,

> This method is just a wrapper for `Collections.synchronizedList(List)`.

So no difference.

Comment: Silly me. Must have missed it. Thanks